# Excel VBA Automation Error on SQL Query

Tags: oracle, excel, vba

I am new to databases and got this query from our database guy.  Unfortunately his last day was yesterday. When I run the query in Oracle SQL Developer it works, returning ~20 records in less than a second, but when I try it in Excel VBA it gives me Runtime Error '-2147217900 (80040e14)' Automation Error on the line "rst.Open StrQuery, cnn".

Here is my code.

```vb
'Initializes variables
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String

'Setup the connection string for accessing MS SQL database
ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Password=XXXXX;User ID=XXXXX;Data Source=XXXXX;"

'Opens connection to the database
cnn.Open ConnectionString
'Timeout error in seconds for executing the entire query
cnn.CommandTimeout = 90

'Query String
StrQuery = "SELECT "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "distinct dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name, "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter, "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name || '-' || dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter as mfg_order_bill, "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.pcb_header.position_seq_nbr || '00', "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "D2.mfg_catg as catg,D2.mfg_catg_value as catgvalue "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "FROM "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.sales_order, "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.planned_shipment, "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.eco_include_exclude, "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.mfg_note_header, "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.pcb_subset, "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.pcb_detail D2, "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.pcb_header, "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.mfg_order "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "WHERE "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name = dbo.pcb_header.mfg_order_name ) and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter = dbo.pcb_header.mfg_bill_letter ) and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_revision = dbo.pcb_header.mfg_order_revision ) and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "( dbo.mfg_order.planned_shipment_nbr = dbo.planned_shipment.planned_shipment_nbr (+) ) and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "( dbo.mfg_order.sales_ord_id = dbo.planned_shipment.sales_ord_id (+) ) and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "( dbo.mfg_order.sales_ord_id = dbo.sales_order.sales_ord_id (+) ) and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "( dbo.pcb_header.pcb_header_id = dbo.pcb_subset.pcb_header_id (+) ) and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name = dbo.eco_include_exclude.mfg_order_name (+) ) and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter = dbo.eco_include_exclude.mfg_bill_letter (+) ) and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_revision = dbo.eco_include_exclude.mfg_order_revision (+) ) and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name = dbo.mfg_note_header.mfg_order_name (+) ) and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter = dbo.mfg_note_header.mfg_bill_letter (+)  ) and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_revision = dbo.mfg_note_header.mfg_order_revision (+) ) and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "(dbo.pcb_header.pcb_header_id = D2.pcb_header_id ) and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.mfg_order.bu_mfg_loc_id = 5 AND "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.pcb_header.prod_code='0050' AND "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_type = 'SO' and "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.pcb_header.mfg_prod_grp   = 'FN05' AND "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "(D2.mfg_catg = 'FSIZ') AND "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "D2.MFG_CATG_VALUE='28FB' AND "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "dbo.mfg_order.MFG_BILL_LETTER='A' AND "
StrQuery = StrQuery & "LENGTH(dbo.mfg_order.MFG_ORDER_NAME)=7;"

'Check Query
Debug.Print StrQuery

'Performs the actual query    
rst.Open StrQuery, cnn

'Dumps all the results from the StrQuery into cell A2 of the first sheet in the active workbook
'Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
End Sub
```

The debug gives me the query:

```
SELECT distinct dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name, dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter, dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name || '-' || dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter as mfg_order_bill, dbo.pcb_header.position_seq_nbr || '00', D2.mfg_catg as catg,D2.mfg_catg_value as catgvalue FROM dbo.sales_order, dbo.planned_shipment, dbo.eco_include_exclude, dbo.mfg_note_header, dbo.pcb_subset, dbo.pcb_detail D2, dbo.pcb_header, dbo.mfg_order WHERE ( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name = dbo.pcb_header.mfg_order_name ) and ( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter = dbo.pcb_header.mfg_bill_letter ) and ( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_revision = dbo.pcb_header.mfg_order_revision ) and ( dbo.mfg_order.planned_shipment_nbr = dbo.planned_shipment.planned_shipment_nbr (+) ) and ( dbo.mfg_order.sales_ord_id = dbo.planned_shipment.sales_ord_id (+) ) and ( dbo.mfg_order.sales_ord_id = dbo.sales_order.sales_ord_id (+) ) and ( dbo.pcb_header.pcb_header_id = dbo.pcb_subset.pcb_header_id (+) ) and ( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name = dbo.eco_include_exclude.mfg_order_name (+) ) and ( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter = dbo.eco_include_exclude.mfg_bill_letter (+) ) and ( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_revision = dbo.eco_include_exclude.mfg_order_revision (+) ) and ( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name = dbo.mfg_note_header.mfg_order_name (+) ) and ( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter = dbo.mfg_note_header.mfg_bill_letter (+)  ) and ( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_revision = dbo.mfg_note_header.mfg_order_revision (+) ) and (dbo.pcb_header.pcb_header_id = D2.pcb_header_id ) and dbo.mfg_order.bu_mfg_loc_id = 5 AND dbo.pcb_header.prod_code='0050' AND dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_type = 'SO' and dbo.pcb_header.mfg_prod_grp   = 'FN05' AND (D2.mfg_catg = 'FSIZ') AND D2.MFG_CATG_VALUE='28FB' AND dbo.mfg_order.MFG_BILL_LETTER='A' AND LENGTH(dbo.mfg_order.MFG_ORDER_NAME)=7;
```

Here it is a little more human readable (Either one of these work in SQL Developer):

```
SELECT 
distinct dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name, 
dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter, 
dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name || '-' || dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter as mfg_order_bill, 
dbo.pcb_header.position_seq_nbr || '00', 
D2.mfg_catg as catg,D2.mfg_catg_value as catgvalue 
FROM 
dbo.sales_order, 
dbo.planned_shipment, 
dbo.eco_include_exclude,    
dbo.mfg_note_header, 
dbo.pcb_subset, 
dbo.pcb_detail D2, 
dbo.pcb_header, 
dbo.mfg_order 
WHERE 
( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name = dbo.pcb_header.mfg_order_name ) and 
( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter = dbo.pcb_header.mfg_bill_letter ) and 
( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_revision = dbo.pcb_header.mfg_order_revision ) and 
( dbo.mfg_order.planned_shipment_nbr = dbo.planned_shipment.planned_shipment_nbr (+) ) and 
( dbo.mfg_order.sales_ord_id = dbo.planned_shipment.sales_ord_id (+) ) and 
( dbo.mfg_order.sales_ord_id = dbo.sales_order.sales_ord_id (+) ) and 
( dbo.pcb_header.pcb_header_id = dbo.pcb_subset.pcb_header_id (+) ) and 
( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name = dbo.eco_include_exclude.mfg_order_name (+) ) and 
( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter = dbo.eco_include_exclude.mfg_bill_letter (+) ) and 
( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_revision = dbo.eco_include_exclude.mfg_order_revision (+) ) and 
( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_name = dbo.mfg_note_header.mfg_order_name (+) ) and 
( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_bill_letter = dbo.mfg_note_header.mfg_bill_letter (+)  ) and 
( dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_revision = dbo.mfg_note_header.mfg_order_revision (+) ) and 
(dbo.pcb_header.pcb_header_id = D2.pcb_header_id ) and 
dbo.mfg_order.bu_mfg_loc_id = 5 AND 
dbo.pcb_header.prod_code='0050' AND 
dbo.mfg_order.mfg_order_type = 'SO' and 
dbo.pcb_header.mfg_prod_grp   = 'FN05' AND 
(D2.mfg_catg = 'FSIZ') AND 
D2.MFG_CATG_VALUE='28FB' AND 
dbo.mfg_order.MFG_BILL_LETTER='A' AND 
LENGTH(dbo.mfg_order.MFG_ORDER_NAME)=7;
```

Comment: Does the query select any uncommon data type, e.g. `LONG`, `CLOB`, `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Everything is either a string or an integer.

Comment: Did you install Oracle client and oledb provider for 32-bit?

Comment: I installed the following from Oracle in the following order:

64-bit ODAC 12.2c Release 1 (12.2.0.1.0) for Windows x64, ODAC122010Xcopy_x64. 

Tried again, no dice.

ODAC 12.2c Release 1 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.2.0.1.0)

Tried again, no luck.

Comment: I assume your Excel is 32-bit. In this case the Oracle client must also be 32-bit.

Comment: Ok, i went back and installed the 12.2.01 32bit client.  Still no luck.  One thing is in all of this experimenting i downloaded and installed Microsoft Power Query and when i start it it tells me my client is deprecated.  So i probably dont have something right here.

Comment: Did you remove Oracle 64 bit installation entirely? Did you install OleDB provider either as component in Oracle Universal installer or from ODAC download. I could open a chat room for further disussion, however in order to join you must have at least 20 reputation, so you should answer 1-2 questions at SO.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you miss the alias for `dbo.pcb_header.position_seq_nbr || '00'`

Try

```
dbo.pcb_header.position_seq_nbr || '00' AS position_seq,
```

Try it like this:

```
'Initializes variables
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
DIM cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String

'Setup the connection string for accessing MS SQL database
ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Password=XXXXX;User ID=XXXXX;Data Source=XXXXX;"

cnn.Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
cnn.CursorLocation = adUseClient


'Opens connection to the database
cnn.Open ConnectionString
'Timeout error in seconds for executing the entire query
cnn.CommandTimeout = 90

Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con
Set rst.Source = cmd
rst.CursorType = adOpenStatic

'Query String
StrQuery = "SELECT "
...

cmd.CommandText = StrQuery 
rst.Open
```

Comment: I am assuming at Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con you meant "cnn" instead of "con" but that still didnt work.  Exact same error at the rst.open.